# c# Console Application Cursor Deletes Char When It Moves

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm working on a notepad on Console Application. When I press left, right, up, down keys it should move cursor. Here's are the code:

```
// For testing cursor moves
static void WriteMethod()
{
    bool Stop = false;
    Console.Clear();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    foreach (string s in NoteLines){ Console.WriteLine(s); }

    // Stop'll be true when esc is pressed but I didn't added it yet
    while(Stop == false)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);

        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                if (Console.CursorLeft > 0) Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
                else Console.SetCursorPosition(0, ((Console.CursorTop > 0) ? Console.CursorTop - 1 : 0));
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                if (Console.CursorLeft + 1 > Console.BufferWidth - 1) Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop + 1);
                else Console.CursorLeft += 1;
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    if (Console.CursorTop > 0) Console.CursorTop -= 1;
                    break;

            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop + 1);
                    break;
            }            
        }
   }
```

Yes cursor moves but before it leaves it deletes char on it. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop);
```

The Console.ReadKey(true) is an optional parameter that chooses to not display the read key.
[Console.ReadKey(Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw(v=vs.110).aspx)